# Inequality Involving Upper Sum

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a Riemann Integrable function on the interval $[a, b]$ then prove that the Upper Sum Of Any partition is greater than $I$ i.e $$U\geq I=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$, here we are taking $U$ as the Upper Sum for partition $P$
$$$$Assume that $U_n$ be the Upper Sum for the partition $P_n$.Let for some partition $P_0$,  $U_0 < I$ so for all partitions finer than $P_0$ we have the Upper Sum $U<U_0$ and hence for all partitions finer than $P_0$ we have $U<U_0 < I$. And as $f(x)$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a, b]$ so for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever $||P||<\delta$ then we have $$|U-I|<\epsilon$$.Chose a $\epsilon_0 < I-U_0$ then there exists a $\delta_0$ such that for norms less than $\delta_0$ we have $$|U-I|<\epsilon_0$$. Now chose a partition $P_1$ finer than $P_0$ such that $||P_1||<\delta_0$ then we have $I-U_1<\epsilon_0$ and also we have $U_1<U_0$. Then for all partitions finer than $||P_1||$ we have $$I-U>I-U_1>I-U_0>\epsilon_0$$, a contradiction. So $U\geq I$
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: Please do something about that horrible formatting, and please remember the importance of commas. Also, introduce your symbols. Don't make your readers guess that $U$ must mean the upper sum corresponding to $P$ (and similarly for $U_0, U_1$.

Comment: Oh sorry for that but is the proof Correct?

Comment: Please make it readable, and then we talk about correctness.

Comment: Oh I will take care of it next time. For now will U plz tell me that is the proof Correct?

Comment: Hey@ Paul Sinclair what happened?

Comment: This is not chat. Nor am I slaved to stay around to have conversations. And again, you need to make the proof reabable **before** we can discuss its correctness. Until then I do not plan on trying to decipher what was intended.

Comment: I have made some corrections. Will U now plz tell me??

Comment: That still falls well short of readable. Come on. You want other people to put in the effort to give you help for no reward, but you can't be bothered to put in the effort to write it nicely so that they can easily follow what you are doing? Spacing. Line breaks. Careful wording. These are things that you should be in your proofs anyway. The purpose of a proof is to convince other people of the truth of the result. A wall of text is not very convincing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $U\gt I$? One can have a function $f=5$ such that on with any partition $U=I$...

Comment: I have corrected it? Now is the proof correct?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair, I have corrected everything, will U now plz tell ?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can read it, I can see that it is correct. A couple of *minor* improvements:

- "Let" is used to indicate you are defining some variable. It does not indicate that you are introducing a hypothetical situation. For that, you should use "suppose":

  > Suppose for some partition $P_0$, the upper sum $U_0 < I$ ...
- What we know directly about $U_1$ is that $|U_1 - I| < \epsilon_0$. While this does directly imply that $I - U_1 < \epsilon_0$, at this point you haven't yet pointed out that $U_1 < U_0 < I$, so it is not immediately clear that $I - U_1 > 0$, which leads the reader to wonder momentarily about the dropped absolute value. I think the logic would flow more cleanly if you first note that as a subpartition sum, $U_1 < U_0 < I$, then note that $I - U_1 < \epsilon_0$.